# How to call a function that is found in a specific view controller at the moment the application is launched?

Tags: ios, objective-c, function

I have some functions in my SecondViewController.m file and I want to call these functions when the application is launched. I have tried to do it like this, but it’s not working.

I have put a print statement in the function to see if it is getting called or not and it appears that the print statement is executed correctly.

Here is the following code:

In SecondViewController.h:

```
@interface AlertsManagementController : UIViewController {
    PushNotificationSettings *pushNotificationSettings;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *switch1;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *switch2;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) PushNotificationSettings *pushNotificationSettings;
```

In SecondViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

appDelegate = (projectAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

pushNotificationSettings = [[PushNotificationSettings alloc] init];
NSDictionary * settings = [pushNotificationSettings getPushSettings];
}

-(void)modificationPush
{
if (switch1.on && switch2.on)
    [switch2 setOn:NO];
printf("Function 1 executed!");
}

-(void)sendTokenFunc{

NSMutableDictionary *preferences1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

if (switch1.on)
    [preferences1 setObject:@"1" forKey:@“switch1”];
else
    [preferences1 setObject:@"0" forKey:@“switch1”];

if (switch2.on)
    [preferences1 setObject:@"1" forKey:@“switch2”];
else
    [preferences1 setObject:@"0" forKey:@“switch2”];

[pushNotificationSettings savePushSettingsWithDictionary:preferences1];
[preferences1 release];

[appDelegate uploadToken:[appDelegate tokenValue]];

printf("Function 2 executed!");
}
```

In appDelegate.m:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

 SecondViewController * vc = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
 [vc modificationPuch];
 [vc sendTokenFunc];

}
```

Comment: Use `NSNotificationCenter` to call that both method from appDelegate

Comment: I've tried to use NSNotificationCenter before, but I've obtained the same result.

Comment: Ok then you can set like `Flag` in appDelegate and then call that method in `viewDidLoad` either directly or by using that flag condition

Comment: It looks to me that the structure if your program needs to change. You should not need to call functions in a view controller like this.  Rather your view controller should refer to a settings object when appropriate.

Comment: According to you secondViewController you are initialising some property on viewDidLoad method and you are calling SecondViewController methods in  AppDelegate by creating object of SecondViewController by init method for instance [[SecondViewController alloc]init];  I think you have to implement 
-(instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
// initialise some property that is required 
    }
    return self;
}

in your SecondViewController class

Comment: try this method of app delegate. - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using NSNotificationCenter.

1. First go to your SecondViewController.m file and in viewDidLoad write the following code.

   ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myNotification:) name:@"myNotification" object:nil];
   ```
2. Then outside viewDidLoad make a function myNotification. I will show you the eg below

   -(void)myNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
   {

   //write the code you wanna excecute when the app opens here

}

3. Go to appDeligate.m and write this code in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

   ```
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myNotification" object:self userInfo:nil];
   ```

Thank you,
Happy coding;)

Answer (score 0):

But if SecondViewController didn't inited, you must get EXC_BAD_ACCESS :)